# Windows Server 2008 intermediate CA has incorrect AIA URL

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, certificate-authority

We have a two tier ADCS PKI and our intermediate CA has the URL for the AIA ending in (1) (ie: http://pki.example.com/certenroll/certificate(1).crt) which of course doesn't exist.  The URL template in the CA extension properties is correct so I think the last time the certificate was issued there was already a file with the same name so it added (1) to the file name.  How do I "reissue" the certificate so that the AIA URL gets updated?

CertUtil -GetReg output:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CertSvc\Configuration\example-Issuing-CA\CACertPublicationURLs:

  CACertPublicationURLs REG_MULTI_SZ =
    0: 1:C:\Windows\system32\CertSrv\CertEnroll\%1_%3%4.crt
    CSURL_SERVERPUBLISH -- 1

    1: 2:ldap:///CN=%7,CN=AIA,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,%6%11
    CSURL_ADDTOCERTCDP -- 2

    2: 2:http://pki.example.com/CertEnroll/%1_%3%4.crt
    CSURL_ADDTOCERTCDP -- 2

CertUtil: -getreg command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the following command (run it on CA server): `certutil -getreg ca\cacertpublicationurls`?

Comment: @CryptoGuy: Added the requested output.

Comment: According to your config, there (in the CertEnroll folder) should be at least two CA certificate files with `.crt` file extension, and one of them with `(1)` suffix at the end. Please, confirm.

Comment: @CryptoGuy: Ahhh... Yes, there are 2 there.  One dated from 2013 and one (the one ending with (1)) dated from 2016,

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: I don't understand why it's creating two?  If I remove both existing certs it recreates two copies of the same cert.

Comment: This is because your CA certificate was renewed, thus you have two CA certificates. MS CA maintains a history of its certificates. So, I don't see any issues in your case.

Comment: Ahhh... Ok.  I see now.  I had 2 certs issued from my root CA for this sub CA and so it is creating each one in the CertEnroll folder.  I'll revoke the earlier cert and leave the most recent.  thanks!

Comment: You don't need to revoke previous CA certificate unless there is a reason. If both certificates share the same key pair, your current CA certificate might be considered revoked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CryptoGuy for the answer that my Root CA had issued two certificates for my issuing CA and that is why one of the certs had a (1) tacked on the end.